# How to remove java.util.NoSuchElementException in the following code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Factorial {
  public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
    int i, f=1, n;
    System.out.println("Enter a no");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        f = f * i;
    }
    System.out.println("factorial is" + f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner#nextInt` thorws `NoSuchElementException` when input is exhausted.

How to remove!- Check valid input by `Scanner#hasNextInt` before calling `Scanner#nextInt`.

```
if(sc.hasNextInt()){
   n=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Read more documentation on [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).

Comment: As this input is coming from stdin, you commenst do not apply.  As per the javadocs `For example, this code allows a user to read a number from System.in:

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i = sc.nextInt();`

Comment: @ScaryWombat, unless OP is closing `System.in`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat And there could be many reason for closing `System.in`. `Scanner#hasNextInt ` provides way to avoid this exception which was my answer precisely.